# regarding setup (object file)

Tags: linux

i have made a firewall project in c language on linux operating system ,now i want to know how to make set of this project so that i can run this application on other system by installing it ?

Answer (score 1):

There's more then one answer to this.  You can use [GNU make](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/) (optionally with [autotools](http://www.gnu.org/software/hello/manual/automake/Autotools-Introduction.html)), [ant](http://ant.apache.org/), [maven](http://maven.apache.org/), [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/), or [Scons](http://www.scons.org/), among many.  Once you have the basic build working, you can package your program as a .deb and/or .rpm so it can be easily installable by users of major GNU/Linux distributions (e.g. Debian and Red Hat).

You should do some research then come back if you have more specific questions.